# Access metadata of objects in DropBox "collection" shared link

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

Using the DropBox iOS App Share link, I use the "Photos" tab to select multiple files to share. It creates a link to an intermediate concept: an anonymous "collection" of photos (not to be mistaken for a folder), of the form:

https://www.dropbox.com/sc/gthm94XXXXXX5ia/XXXXXXbQoskcY3EqcOmx2hiEa

If I use a signed-in web browser, I can see a perfectly usable UI to browse the collection and download a .ZIP. However, this link doesn't appear to be amenable to any of the DropBox APIs. I can't find any mention in the API reference about "collection"-type links like this.

I *can* get it to appear from `get_shared_links`:

```
{
     ".tag": "collection",
     "url": "https://www.dropbox.com/sc/xxxxx/xxxxxxx",
     "visibility": {
         ".tag": "public"
     }
}
```

I cannot get metadata with `https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata?url=...` probably because this does not correspond to a *path*:

```
{
  "error_summary": "shared_link_not_found/..",
  "error": {
    ".tag": "shared_link_not_found"
  }
}
```

How do I extract the metadata for the individual images within? In particular I want to create permanent shared links for each of them, and get temporary streaming links for them.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Breaking-down-a-multiple-file-share-link-into-individual-items/m-p/210097#M10469 ]